# Corrupted hard drive in external hard drive bay

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I did something very stupid and unplugged my USB3 Hard drive dock from my machine while it had a Samsung SSD attached. Unfortunately the drive seems to have some tables corrupted.

When I run `chkdsk` on the drive using the parameter `/F` (fix errors), it recognizes the drive has an NTFS file system, however, it fails with the error `Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted.`.

In disk management, the drive is detected and has the following view:

[image: Disk management view]

It appears though as the largest partition (the 464.79 GB one) is the only one corrupted as the other partitions appear to have valid values (i.e first 500 MB partition is accessible and the recovery partition seems valid).

The corrupted partition reads that it is 100% free, but is inaccessible from Windows Explorer and is labeled as "RAW".

I have started a Recuva deep scan recovery to another external hard drive and although I believe I can "recover" most files (2.3 million seems accurate), the folder structure is mostly destroyed which is a very very significant inconvenience for me.

This drive is for my main PC that I don't have with me, therefore the data on it is of great importance. The key thing to remember about this drive is that the data wasn't overwritten or formatted, I believe simply some headers are corrupted and all of my files should still be there.

I would greatly appreciate any tips on how to recover the drive / fix the headers. Thanks.

Current recovery status:
- Recuva has completed backing up all files.
- O&O DataRecovery actually was able to find folders (not all but a lot), however, the files seem to be scrambled because some files I know what are in them but then I see the contents of another file.

Comment: Before you make any changes to the drive's contents, make a complete byte-for-byte backup of the entire drive. This will allow you to get back to your current state no matter what happens. Among other things, this will allow you to safely try multiple recovery schemes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good idea, will do.